# Required resource for a basic on demand video streaming service/app

Tags: video-streaming, azure-media-services, video-on-demand

I want to create an e-learning app. The app will have option to upload videos and then same videos will be streamed to user.

I was looking for Azure-Media-Services. I want to know what resources are required other than Azure-Media-Service. Can anyone give a list of service which will be required to crate that kind on app. Using that list I will be to analyze the cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal required services are:

- [Azure Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/azure/media-services/latest/media-services-overview)
- [Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/)
- you will probably need a [Streaming Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/streaming-endpoint-concept)
- some kind of server [Web App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) or [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) for app logic

As far as I know, there is no support in the Azure portal for creating Azure Media Services v3 (only v2) infrastructure in the UI so you must use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Creating bare minimum infra (without Web App or Azure function):

```
az login
az account set --subscription <your-subscription-id>
az ams account create --name <name-of-your-video-library> -g <resource-group> --storage-account <name-of-storage-account> -l <datacentre-location>
az ams account sp create --account-name <name-of-your-video-library> --resource-group <resource-group>
```

In case of an error that principal already exists run:

```
 az ams account sp reset-credentials --account-name <name-of-your-video-library> --resource-group <resource-group>
```

And you also need to start your streaming endpoint

```
az ams streaming-endpoint start -n default -a <name-of-your-video-library> -g <resource-group>
```

And you are ready to go.